# How to apply complex function over multiple same-sized arrays to create new same sized array with numpy in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that takes x and y locations and performs a nearest neighbor search. I would like to apply this function over the two array so that I can get the results of the functions at each point in the array. I have given here some sample data and the actual function I would like to apply. I also have a call to the function  for a single point. How can I apply this function for each x,y pair that occurs at matching indexes from my arrays `xs` and `ys`?

```
import scipy.spatial
import scipy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def est_bathymetry(x,y,bathymetry_data,gsl_level=1278.3,n=4):
    
    grid_xy=np.array([x,y]).T
    
    def do_kdtree(grid_xy,points, n):
    #This function gets the kd tree for the sample, then returns the closest
    #points to each grid node as indices
        points=points[:2,:]
        points=list(points.transpose())
        mytree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(points)
        dist, indexes = mytree.query(grid_xy, k=n, n_jobs=-1)
        return dist, indexes
        
    dist, indexes = do_kdtree(grid_xy,bathymetry_data.iloc[:,0:2].values.T,n)    
    
    avg_bath=np.nanmean(np.take(bathymetry_data['Bathymetry'], indexes))
    
    return avg_bath
    
#create sample data
x=np.linspace(0,10,11,endpoint=True)
xs=np.tile(x,(11,1))

ys=xs.T

np.random.seed(123)


data=pd.DataFrame([np.random.uniform(0,10,100),np.random.uniform(0,10,100),np.random.normal(2000,100,100)]).T
data.columns=['Lat','Long','Bathymetry']


#example of function working on single input
avg_bathymetry=est_bathymetry(x=np.min(xs),y=np.min(ys),bathymetry_data=data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that with np.vectorize I could vectorize and apply the function this function actually is applyable, but I needed to remove the other inputs. The only problem is it will take 225 days to run with the full data set. Going to have to go back to the drawing board with this.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is slow